# Did Instagram change the limit of users that I can have in a single JSON?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, instagram

I am trying to write a Python script that scrapes followers from a given Instagram account.
For doing this, I use Selenium, inject in the HTML a .js script to fetch the URL for the request and then do the request with the fetched URL until I don't have all the followers of that account.
The decoded URL looks like this:

```
https://instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=17888483320059182&variables={"id":"<the profile's ID>","first":<a number from 0 to 6000>}
```

In which, "ID" is the identifier for the given account and "first" represents the number of followers that the response's JSON should contain (which I determined to approximately be 6000 as a maximum). If the account has more followers, the next request would contain an "after" parameter which would indicate a possibility to continue the call.
This worked until a week ago. I am now getting

```
{"message": "execution failure", "errors": [{"message": "Something is wrong. Please check your input and try again.", "locations": []}], "data": {"user": null}, "status": "fail"}
```

This only happens if I give to the parameter "first" a value which is greater than 50. Less than that, it works.
Is it a new limitation from Instagram? Does anybody happen to know something?